# how to check cuda availability(C++)?

Tags: cuda

is it possible to check if any CUDA devices are present before all cudaMalloc... commands are called?

im using C++ and i just want to print an error message before the program launches incase the user doesn't support cuda tech.

EDIT: if i can check it from C#, it will be even better.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cudaGetDeviceCount` to get the number of cuda devices and use cuda device properties to retrieve your necessary compute capabilities.

A rather old version of the API documentation for `cudaGetDeviceCount` can be found [here](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g665468e8cb33be42434f11bee2684ec9.html).